# How can the complete hierarchy of the parent child relation ship be shown in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, parent-child, parent, relation

Some background --- 
I have two tables 
One - table lists all the entities in the system , 
the other specifies the relationship between the entities

Ask --
The ask is looking at the tables can we chart out relationship for each of the child entity to the parent.

-- What I have done

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE rell AS 
  SELECT 3 child_id, 2 parent_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 12 ;

CREATE TEMP TABLE mapp AS 
  SELECT 1 item_id, 'app' type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 , 'app'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 , 'app'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 14 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12 , 'ci' ;
```

The above listing 'mapp' has all the entities ( type - app are the final parent )  and the rel table has the relations.

Can I have the output of something like below

```
original_child  final_parent    path
4   1   4>1
3   1   3>2>1
7   5   7>8>5
14  1   14>6>2>1
15  1   15>14>6>2>1
11  12  11>12
2   1   2>1
8   5   8>5
6   1   6>2>1
```

Comment: BigQuery doesn't support recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries.  You can do this with a script but not a single query.

Comment: I just answered a really similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234264/bigquery-construct-hierarchy-array-from-key-master-slave/61303711#61303711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So after much struggle of searching the internet and trying out multiple options here is what I have come up with , it took a lot of time to understand the details but I think I have found a solution. Maybe it will save people of the trouble that I went though. I will try to explain as I go

```
-- Initialise variables 
DECLARE steps INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE table_holder ARRAY<STRUCT<original_child INT64, latest_parent INT64,path STRING>>;

--- Set up dummy tables 

CREATE TEMP TABLE rell AS 
  SELECT 3 child_id, 2 parent_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 12 ;

CREATE TEMP TABLE mapp AS 
  SELECT 1 item_id, 'app' type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 , 'app'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 , 'app'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 14 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15 , 'ci'  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12 , 'ci' ;


  SET table_holder = (
            SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a.item_id,
            b.parent_id,    CONCAT(CAST(a.item_id AS STRING),">",CAST(b.parent_id AS STRING)))
            ) cls from mapp a inner join rell b  on a.item_id = b.child_id where a.type!='app') ;




    LOOP 
   SET table_holder = (
   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a.original_child,
      coalesce(b.parent_id,a.latest_parent),   coalesce( CONCAT(path,">",CAST(b.parent_id AS STRING)),path))
      ) cls from UNNEST (table_holder) a left outer join rell b  on a.latest_parent = b.child_id ) ;  

  SET steps = steps+1;
  IF steps=5 THEN LEAVE; END IF;

    END LOOP;


   SELECT * from UNNEST (table_holder);
```

Arrays and struct have been utilised as they are easier to play with. and bigquery scripting has been used for looping. Runaway condition can be increased if people expect many levels.

Here is the final output

```
original_child  final_parent    path
4   1   4>1
3   1   3>2>1
7   5   7>8>5
14  1   14>6>2>1
15  1   15>14>6>2>1
11  12  11>12
2   1   2>1
8   5   8>5
6   1   6>2>1
```

Hope it helps someone down the line for similar exercise.